# Flutter | Dart - Not able to launch windows app on double Tap

Tags: flutter, windows, dart

I created a release build for windows platform but when I double tap on .exe then application is not getting launch.

I am able to launch when I run using flutter command or visual studio.

I want to launch flutter windows release or debug app using double tap.

Comment: Application shows only in task manager but there is no window